# how can i use a wildcard in ID selector while binding event for a dynamically added element?

Tags: jquery, css

i have multiple anchor tags added to the document with id="btnsavecontinue-1","btnsavecontinue-2","btnsavecontinue-3", and so on.i need to bind a click event on the anchor tags,
this is what i did

```
$('.tabsTD').on('click', 'a[id*="btnsavecontinue-"]',(function () {
alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
);
```

But i couldn't get it to work
please help 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give class **btnsavecontinue** to all anchor tags.

**Then Try**

```
   $(document).on('click', '.btnsavecontinue',(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[id^="btnsavecontinue-"]',(function () {
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
}));
```

Comment: nice thought but i rather need my selector working,thanks for the response though